# RegEx, preg_replace_callback Question PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

This is what I've got for for my RegEx, I was wondering if this is the best way.

I want to be able to find something similar regardless of the spacing between Identifiers and not be case sensitive.  And if possible, not worry about order..

Example:

```
[Foreclosure ="Remax" URL="http://www.remax.com" Title = "4 Bedroom 2 Bath Condo"]
[Foreclosure ="Remax"URL="http://www.remax.com"Title="4 Bedroom 2 Bath Condo"]
[Foreclosure  =   "Remax"    URL="http://www.remax.com"     Title = "4 Bedroom 2 Bath Condo"    ]
```

Here's my existing Code:

```
function ForeclosureCode_filter( $buffer )
{
    //There might be a better way to do the regex...  But this seems to work...
    $buffer = preg_replace_callback( '@\[Forclosure *=*"(.*?)" *url *=*"(.*?)" *title="(.*?)" *\]@si',
        "ForeclosureCode_replace", $buffer );
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: That sounds condescending... Answer: 0 or more of previous expression.  
In my defense, I've not used RegEx very much at all..

Comment: Why the several =* then?

Comment: Because I don't really know what I'm doing with RegEx... It's still a little confusing to me.  I'm at least "TRYING" to figure it out, VS ask someone else to do all the work for me.  I could have said here's this what's the regex for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `\s*` to match indefinite amounts of whitespace; this allows you to include all forms of whitespace, not just regular spaces (and thus you can match tabs, etc).

```
'@\[Foreclosure\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*url\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\s*title="(.*?)"\s*\]@si'
```